# create a downloadable csv from a json string

Tags: javascript, php, json, csv, data-conversion

**Target**: write&download a csv file starting with a json string, for example data.csv containing

```
col1,col2,col3
"324","19-08-2014","13000"
"325","19-08-2014","5010"
```

**What I have done until now**:

1) iframe and button to call my conversion function

```
<iframe id="frame" style="display:none"></iframe>
<form><input type="submit" value="Export CSV" onclick="javascript:Download();"></form>
```

2) my Download() function which would want to download my csv file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Download(){
        var csv=ConvertToCSV(<?php echo $json_string ?>);
        var url='data:application/csv,'+csv;
        var _iframe_dl = $('<iframe />')
        .attr('src', url)
        .hide()
        .appendTo('body');
    };
 </script>
```

3) my json to csv conversion function which tries to create a csv string

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function ConvertToCSV(json) {
    var array = typeof json != 'object' ? JSON.parse(json) : json;
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var line = '';
        for (var index in array[i]) {
            if (line != '') line += ','
                line += '"'+array[i][index]+'"';
        }
        str += line + "\r\n";
    }
    return str;
}
</script>
```

**Encountered problems** :

i) it seems that it doesn't recognize \r\n, infact output is just one line

```
"324","19-08-2014","13000""325","19-08-2014","5010"
```

ii) I cannot set the filename and the extension, infact the downloaded file is "download" without extension containing the single line mentioned above

Comment: If you have the data server-side already (as `<?php echo $json_string ?>` suggests) – then why don’t you handle creating the download output in PHP as well?

Comment: it would mean creating another .php file to be called, isn't it. If so, I would have avoided this.

Comment: It would mean another request, yes. It that is what you want to avoid here – then I would at least create the Data URI value server-side already, instead of doing it client-side …

Comment: Anyway, if you want to do it this way: You should at least URL-encode the data you put into the URI, using `encodeURIComponent`. Otherwise, it might contain characters/byte values that simply break the format.

Comment: Because the data is already server-side, why not setup a server-side call that gives you the data in the way you want? I am not familiar with PHP, but could you do all the work including the creation of the file and just download the results? I would love to know if PHP can do this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to ensure your data is in this format, like the example below.

```
var array = [["col1","col2","col3"],["324","19-08-2014","13000"],["324","19-08-2014","13000"]]
```

then you need to create csv variable as shown below

```
var csv = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,";
```

after this you need to loop through your data array and append each line to the csv variable you just set.

```
array.forEach(function(arrayItem, index){

   arrayAsString = arrayItem.join(",");
   csv += index < array.length ? arrayAsString+ "\n" : arrayAsString;

});
```

now to give this file a name and create a download link you must create a hidden anchor node and set its download attribute.

```
var encUri = encodeURI(csv);
var link = document.createElement("a");
link.setAttribute("href", encUri);
link.setAttribute("download", "file_name.csv");
//add anchor element to body    
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
```

**EDIT:**
Tested on Chrome and is working, also on Safari. Does not work on Firefox for some reason which i will take a look at now

I found out that if you add the link into the body of the page only then will Firefox initiate the download, you can use a code like so. I have updated my code above

```
document.body.appendChild(link);
```